# receiving complex objects from server in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I saw that ExtGWT has RPC which transfers objects between server and client easily. How can this be achieved in ExtJS? Is there any way to have js classes that get loaded automatically from server's response like ExtGWT does?

The server is Java-based and it uses Jersey REST-based framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Ext GWT, nor do I work with Java often, but I think you can modify your web service to send you JSON data that describes your objects (using a JSON Serializer).

On the client side, if you want to display your objects into a grid (for example), you can configure your Ext.data.Record to look into your object and pull out the information in a flat form that can be loaded into a store.

Comment: What about things you don't want to display on the client. Say the client receives some complex data that it needs to compute first and then do some actions? Do you define javascript classes that reflect the server classes? How do you fill these classes with server data?

Comment: The web apps I have worked with typically pack user-facing data into a list of flat objects or arrays, with all of the complicated processing happening on the web server (or sql server if possible).  This way, we don't have similar code on the server and on the client (maintaining this can suck).  Does this not serve your purpose?

Comment: Yes, I can't find a better way myself - so I'll stick with this for the moment. Thank you!